# which way is good for use memcached , more instances with small memory or less instances with big memory?

Tags: memcached

I am preparing hardwares for memcaced server and I have a question:

Should I start more instances with less memory or less instances with big memory ? For Example,to start an instance with a memory of 128G with one port or start 16 instance with a memory of 128G with 16 port ,which is the better one for memcached?

Comment: It depends how you're using it.

Comment: I just use it to cache the query DB results,and no special usages.And can you list some advantages for each way?